# semaphore operation in linux,receive SIGSEGV and segmentation fault,which part is wrong?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

My thread functions are:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"sys/types.h"
#include"pthread.h"
#include"semaphore.h"

sem_t sem;
int running = 1;
int ret;
void *pf(void *arg)          //producer function
{
    int semval;
    while(running)
    {
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&sem); 
        sem_getvalue(&sem,&semval); 
        printf("produce : %d\n",semval);
    }

}

void *cf(void *arg)         /*consumer function*/
{
    int semval;
    while(running)
    {
        sleep(1);
        sem_wait(&sem); 
        sem_getvalue(&sem,&semval);
        printf("consume : %d\n",semval);
    }
}
```

and main function is:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t pf, cf;
    ret = sem_init(&sem,0,16);
    pthread_create(&pf,NULL,(void *)pf,NULL);   /*create producer*/
    pthread_create(&cf,NULL,(void *)cf,NULL);   /*create consumer*/
    sleep(1);
    running = 0;
    pthread_join(pf,NULL);
    pthread_join(cf,NULL);
    sem_destroy(&sem);  
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the executable file, it returns segmentation fault. I think the program maybe access invalid memory, but I don't know which part of my code is wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You have named your thread variables and functions with the same name: `pf` and `cf`. So the variables [*shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the function names. It's never a good idea to have same name for variables and functions.

Change

```
pthread_create(&pf,NULL,(void *)pf,NULL);   /*create producer*/
pthread_create(&cf,NULL,(void *)cf,NULL);   /*create consumer*/
```

to

```
pthread_create(&pf,NULL,producer,NULL);   /*create producer*/
pthread_create(&cf,NULL,consumer,NULL);   /*create consumer*/
```

and rename your functions to `producer` and `consumer` respectively. Note that the casting is wrong too (and needless even if you cast is correctly) which I have removed.

You are returning any values from the thread functions. Thread functions should return `void *`. So you need to call [`pthread_exit(NULL);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) or return a null pointer.

Another major problem is you are accessing the variable `running` without any synchronization which leads to [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Depending on the thread scheduling, if `main` thread sets `running` to `0` before the threads get to execute then your threads may not execute the while loop at all.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!  I just start to learn network programming.

Comment: Regarding the `running` flag: that's not exactly UB. It's just not what the OP might have expected. (in general, it doesn't matter much in what order such a flag is accessed)

Comment: @FelixPalmen No. It is UB: Any race condition is UB.

Comment: Considering the standard until `C11` doesn't tell anything about concurrency (and this example is using `pthreads`), no, it's not UB by means of the standard. You can't predict the order of execution of the threads, but that's something different.

Comment: @FelixPalmen C11 states: C11, 5.1.2.4, **The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.** The fact is `running` is accessed (main writes and thread functions by multiple threads without any synchronization. I don't think posix defines race condition to not be UB.

Comment: Yes, this is about `C11` threads. The C standard doesn't know about *POSIX* threads. If `C11` threads were used here, yes, this would be strictly speaking UB because there's no guarantee that an `int` access is atomic. (To be clear: The result is the same, I'm just talking about the definition of UB by means of the standard ;) )

Comment: POSIX doesn't guarantee `int` access is atomic either. The term *undefined* may not be present or explicitly stated in POSIX with respect to race condtion, but it can't be well-defined. Anything that's not well-defined is undefined. POSIX generally states C standard overrules it. So pthreads not being a part of C standards is a silly reason to claim that race condition is not undefined.

Comment: Just talking about the **terms** here. Anything exceeding the standard is *implementation defined* (from the C standard POV) and of course, a race condition can't be *well defined*. I updated my answer to elaborate on this problem with the code, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
pthread_t pf, cf;
ret = sem_init(&sem,0,16);
pthread_create(&pf,NULL,(void *)pf,NULL);   /*create producer*/
pthread_create(&cf,NULL,(void *)cf,NULL);   /*create consumer*/
```

you are actually passing your *thread descriptors* to `pthread_create()` as the start routine. They have the same names as the functions you seem to mean here, but shadow them. Also note `void *` is a pointer to data, which is incompatible with a function pointer -> do *not* cast to `void *` here.

Correct code would e.g. look like this:

```
pthread_t pt, ct;
ret = sem_init(&sem,0,16);
pthread_create(&pt,NULL,pf,NULL);   /*create producer*/
pthread_create(&ct,NULL,cf,NULL);   /*create consumer*/
```

BTW, general hint: Enable compiler warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` would have told you what is wrong.

**edit:** following the discussion on *Blue Moon*'s answer: Just using an `int` to shut down your threads is *indeed* problematic. The data race occuring here doesn't matter in practice most of the time, because normally, you only want to tell your threads to stop and don't care, when exactly this is happening. But (and that's a big **but**): Your compiler sees this code:

```
while(running)
{
    [...]
}
```

where the condition for `while` is the **only** access to `running` in this function. Not knowing about concurrency, it could legally assume that `running`, once read, never changes. So, reading it once and using this read value (e.g. stored in a register) for the loop condition forever would be a *valid* optimization and definitely not what you want.

Oh, and adding a `volatile` to `running` is *not* the solution, but explanations of this tend to be lengthy, just google for it.

One possibility would be to use a semaphore for stopping the thread, too. E.g. I have this in one of my threaded projects:

```
/* check whether daemon shutdown was requested */
if (!sem_trywait(&forceExit))
{
    /* pass on to next thread */
    sem_post(&forceExit);
    rcout = -2;
    break;
}
```

The main thread just does a single `sem_post(&forceExit)` to shut all other threads down.